# Range of valid indices for glGenTextures, glGenBuffers

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm programming OpenGL 1.1 ES in Android, i.e. using fixed pipeline.

I'm using `glGenTextures` and `glGenBuffers`, which return an index in array (I use them only for one texture/buffer at a time). What is the guaranteed valid (and invalid) range of this index?

Empirically, I observed that valid indices start with 1, but documentation doesn't mention anything about it. Is the value 0 guaranteed to be invalid?

I need it because sometimes I need to check if a texture/buffer was loaded already or not. If 0 can be valid, I need to initialize my values to -1 (to be able to detect that they are uninitialized/unloaded), but if 0 is invalid texture/buffer name, then things are easier.

In Android, an `int[]` is filled, but in OpenGL ES API, I saw that there are `GLUint` values there. So I'm afraid that (in theory) even initializing to -1 in my Android program can be incorrect, because (in theory) an uint can return 0xFFFFFFFF.

So what is the valid range, and what is the invalid range/value that I can be sure that it doesn't represent a valid texture/buffer name (index)?

Comment: If you're using OpenGL ES 1.1, you can check texture validity with ``GLES11.glIsTexture(int)``.

Comment: Thanks! According to the description of glIsTexture(texture), it seems zero is never a texture name: "If texture is zero, or is a non-zero value that is not currently the name of a texture, or if an error occurs, glIsTexture returns GL_FALSE." I wonder if a similar function exists about hardware buffers (to learn if the same rule applies there too).

Comment: Yes, I found a glIsBuffer. Its description is similar: "            If buffer is zero, ...", i.e. it always returns false if the argument is 0. I think this means we can be 100% sure that a zero value is never a valid texture name or buffer object name, right?